# Advanced Method of Range Class Failed

Tags: excel, vba, advanced-filter

I have the following code that copies unique values and pastes them in a new column. However I get an error saying "Advanced Method of Range Class Failed". However when I debug the program and without changing the code click the run button, the macro runs smoothly. Not sure why an error occurs originally.

Here is the code:

```
Dim W2 As Worksheet
Set W2 = Worksheets("Tickets&VCON")

W2.Range("W3:AQ52").ClearContents

'Copy unique values for netting
Application.CutCopyMode = False
W2.Range("B2:B52").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Range("X2:X52"), Unique:=True
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue may be, but it may help to fully qualify your `CopyToRange:=` range like `CopyToRange:=W2.Range("X2:X52")` otherwise it will default to `ActiveSheet.Range("X2:X52")` which at that point in code execution may not be what you want.

Comment: You're doing something wrong in the first part of your code. Why don't you share it?